# Google Mocks test output to XML not working

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have been using Google Test for a few months now and I have

```
--gtest_output=xml:$(TargetDir)\$(SolutionName).unittest.results.$
```

(Configuration).xml

as command Arguments in the VS2010 Test project. This has been working
to output the test results to xml.

I now have been adding in Google Mocks and I have the tests working and Google Mocks working, but now I don't get the test result in a file. How do I get the XML file of the test results and mock results?

I have not been able to find any information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of my mock functions was not returning a valid value and the test application was exiting before the XML file was generated. After I fixed my Unit Test that need this extra setup on the mocked function. The Unit Tests all complete and the XML file is generated.

Comment: the ProgressiveXMLTestListener patch in http://markmail.org/thread/w4ylvzw3jgnpumfu can help with issues like this